# How to override override modeline customization from org-faces.el?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, dot-emacs

org-faces.el contains this code

```
(org-copy-face 'mode-line 'org-mode-line-clock
  "Face used for clock display in mode line.")

;; ...snip...

(provide 'org-faces)

;;; org-faces.el ends here
```

Which makes the right side of my modeline (the org clock display) have the same face as 'mode-line.  Using my .emacs I'd like to change this behavior so that the org clock display uses the same face as 'mode-line-inactive.

I tried adding this to .emacs:

```
(require 'org-faces) ;;necessary?
(org-copy-face 'mode-line-inactive 'org-mode-line-clock
  "Face used for clock display in mode line."
  :background "blue")
(provide 'org-faces) ;;necessary?
```

but the modeline is unchanged after evaluating .emacs.  Where am I going wrong?  I'm pretty new to Lisp. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should redefine the face, as I do for "org-todo":

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil
                    :weight 'bold :box '(:line-width 1 :color "#D8ABA7")
                    :foreground "#D8ABA7" :background "#FFE6E4")
```

You may (or must, maybe, depending on where you place the above lines) leave the requiring of org-faces, but clearly not the provide line.

Alternatively, use a color theme that improves Org's use (such as my Emacs Leuven theme, see https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven-theme), eventually customizing it to suit your taste.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. [This screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7713778/org-mode-line-clock.png) shows my problem. I'm using set-face-attribute in .emacs to color the active modeline green.  The result of that is that the org clock on the **inactive** modelines are also green.  I want all the org clocks to be the same color as the inactive mode line. Is changing the org-todo face the right path?  Is that related to the org clock in the modeline?  Adding this code to .emacs with and requiring org-faces immediately before or after it, doesn't change anything.

Comment: OK, now I think I understand your question: you want o-m-line-clock to be gray (as mode-line-inactive) when the window is inactive, and the same face to be green (as mode-line-active) when the window is active, right?  In that case, I don't have a solution -- I have the same problem. And I don't think it's possible in current Emacs (like you still can't have different backgrounds per mode, for example).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "org-faces"
  '(set-face-attribute 'org-mode-line-clock nil
                       :inherit nil))
```

That is, make the `org-mode-line-clock` no longer inherit attributes from the `mode-line` face.  It seems like it gets the attributes from `mode-line` or `mode-line-inactive` as appropriate, when displayed in the mode line.